# Octave - How to plot an "infinite"(= Defining the function on [0:35916] for me) sawtooth function

Tags: octave

I know how to plot a sawtooth function (thanks to another forum) but only on the domain `[0:10]` thanks to the following code which is actually working :

```
t=0:0.04:10;
A=1;
T=1;
rho= mod(t * A / T, A);
plot(t,rho)
```

A=the amplitude, T=the period,t=the time interval.
The problem is that I need the same function on the domain `[0:35916]` but when I try to adapt this code to do so (eg by extending the time interval), I get an error and I don't understand why.

error:

> plt2vv: vector lengths must match error: called from plt>plt2vv at line 487 column 5 plt>plt2 at line 246 column 14 plt at line 113 column 17 plot at line 222 column 10

Comment: "I get an error". Please be specific. What error do you get? You should copy-paste the error message into your question. It'll make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: Ok thank you. Here is the following error.>>  t = 0:0.04:10;
>>  A = 1;
>>  T = 1;
>>  rho= mod(t * A / T, A);
>> plot(t,rho)
>>  t = 0:1:35916;
>> plot(t,rho)
error: __plt2vv__: vector lengths must match
error: called from
    __plt__>__plt2vv__ at line 487 column 5
    __plt__>__plt2__ at line 246 column 14
    __plt__ at line 113 column 17
    plot at line 222 column 10

Comment: Please [edit] your original question to include this.  Please include a link from where you got that code

Comment: You have updated `t` but you didn't update `rho`. `rho` is initialised for your previous value of `t` and needs to be updated. Voting to close this post.

Comment: error: __plt2vv__: vector lengths must match
error: called from
    __plt__>__plt2vv__ at line 487 column 5
    __plt__>__plt2__ at line 246 column 14
    __plt__ at line 113 column 17
    plot at line 222 column 10

Comment: How can I update rho exactly ? I'm a newbie in Octave .

Comment: Just like you initialised it in the first place

Answer (score 2):

Simply modifying the original upper limit of your interval from 10 to 35916 should do the trick:

```
t=0:0.04:35916;
A=1;
T=1;
rho= mod(t * A / T, A);
plot(t,rho)
```

The code above yields the following image:

[image]

Of course it is up to you to adjust `A` and `T` to suit your needs.